# Debian 12 Bookworm running OpenSSH_9.2 only allows rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256 and ssh-rsa server host key algorithms

Tags: ssh, debian-bookworm

On a Debian 12 Bookworm (running OpenSSH_9.2), which was recently upgraded from Debian 11, only the **rsa-sha2-512**, **rsa-sha2-256**  server host key algorithms are available by default. Setting `HostKeyAlgorithms +additional-algorithm-to-use` in sshd_config (which is in itself very basic) allows only for the addition of **ssh-rsa** but not the others. The man page for HostKeyAlgorithms lists the following as default (which I would expect to work out of the box):

- ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,
- sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,
- sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
- rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,
- rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,
- ssh-ed25519,
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,
- sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,
- sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,
- rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256

The `ssh -Q HostKeyAlgorithms` query for available algorithms returns:

- ssh-ed25519
- ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
- sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
- sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
- ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
- sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
- sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
- webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
- ssh-dss
- ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
- ssh-rsa
- ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
- rsa-sha2-256
- rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com
- rsa-sha2-512
- rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com

For example, when attemting to connect from the same host using `ssh localhost -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 -vvv`, I get `"Unable to negotiate with 127.0.0.1 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa`
I installed a plain Debian 12 VM locally to compare the behaviour, and when I ran the same command, the negotiation was successful.

I would really appreciate suggestions on how to make other host key algorithms available.

Comment: Did you compare the sshd_config on the upgraded system and the plain local system? What are the differences?

Comment: Do the files `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_{ecdsa,ed25519}_key{,.pub}` exist with appropriate contents and correct ownership (root) and permissions (600,644 or less)? If not I _think_ there is a way to get dpkg to redo the package's configure step which should generate the needed keys; failing that try `ssh-keygen -A` with sudo or similar. Note `ssh -Q` tells you what algorithms are _implemented_ by a particular version and build, not which ones can or will actually be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comment posted by dave_thompson_085, I took the following steps to fix the issue (as root user):

1. Backed up the current key files located in `/etc/ssh/`
2. Removed the current key files from `/etc/ssh/`
3. Run `ssh-keygen -A` to regenerate host keys
4. Generated keys for additional key types needed. E.g. `ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_sha2_nistp384_key`
5. Ensured that for every key type to be used there is a HostKey entry in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file matching the host key file name and location. E.g. `HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key`
6. Specified the additional non default keys to be used in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. E.g. `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`. Comma separated list can be used to add more. ssh-rsa added only for required backwards compatibility in this case.
7. Restarted sshd

Note: Just because something can be enabled doesn't mean that it should be enabled even if it seems like the simplest solution. Please check whether it meets you required security levels.